# Watch array of object and trust html in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one controller that add items to the list and trust the content using :

```
app.controller('main', function($scope, $sce, sharedService) {
  this.sharedService = =sharedService;
  this.sharedService.items = [];
  this.newItem = () => {
    this.sharedService.items.push({
      html: ''
    });
  };
  $scope.$watch(() => this.sharedService.items, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    newValue.forEach(function(item) {
        item.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.html);
    });
  }, true);
});
```

but I got error `Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html` in other view I'm displaying the list of items using ng-bind-html and it display html but why I got this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error because `$watch` was triggered again when I change `item.html`. To fix it I add check if `item.html` is already ***trusted***:

```
if (item.html && !item.html.$$unwrapTrustedValue) {
    item.value = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.value);
}
```